# Get picture from camera without saving to gallery - Android

Tags: java, android, camera

I need to find a way to capture a picture from camera into bitmap without saving it to the gallery. all the ways i've seen using the "MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE" Intent saving the picture captured to the gallery before passing the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your pictures straight from your cell to facedropt synced pictures on your facebook account then delete the gallery...no one can see pictures from facedropt unless you allow to be shared.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question, I'm building an app and i need to find a way to capture image from camera to Bitmap object without saving it to gallery.